# Cloudflare R2 : get usage metrics through the API

Tags: cloudflare, metrics, bucket, cloudflare-r2

I can't find how to get usage metrics to my R2 bucket through Cloudflare's API.

I'd like to get the bucket size and the number of class A and class B operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use their `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql` endpoint for both of those queries. Which is what their frontend does anyways. I'm writing this in `nodejs` but I did see that this can be done with cURL instead if needed.

I mainly followed their [docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/reference/metrics-analytics/#operations-dataset).

Here is a JavaScript file which does both requests. If you wanted to filter to a certain bucket you would add the bucketName prop to the filter. However, keep in mind operation requests for billing purposes are account wide not per bucket.

```js
// main.js
const date = new Date()
date.setDate(1) // set to first of the month

const res = await fetch('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-AUTH-EMAIL': process.env.EMAIL,
    'X-AUTH-KEY': process.env.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `{
      viewer {
        accounts(filter: { accountTag: "${process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT}" }) {
          r2OperationsAdaptiveGroups(
            filter: { datetime_geq: "${date.toISOString()}" }
            limit: 9999
          ) {
            dimensions {
              actionType
            }
            sum {
              requests
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`
  })
})

const body = await res.json()
const classA = ["ListBuckets", "PutBucket", "ListObjects", "PutObject", "CopyObject", "CompleteMultipartUpload", "CreateMultipartUpload", "ListMultipartUploads", "UploadPart", "UploadPartCopy", "ListParts", "PutBucketEncryption", "PutBucketCors", "PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration"]
const classB = ["HeadBucket", "HeadObject", "GetObject", "UsageSummary", "GetBucketEncryption", "GetBucketLocation", "GetBucketCors", "GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration"]
let [classATotal, classBTotal] = [0, 0]
body.data.viewer.accounts[0].r2OperationsAdaptiveGroups.forEach(item => {
  if (classA.includes(item.dimensions.actionType)) {
    classATotal += item.sum.requests
  } else if (classB.includes(item.dimensions.actionType)) {
    classBTotal += item.sum.requests
  }
})

const aUsage = Math.round((classATotal / 1_000_000) * 100)
const bUsage = Math.round((classBTotal / 10_000_000) * 100)

const storage = await fetch('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-AUTH-EMAIL': process.env.EMAIL,
    'X-AUTH-KEY': process.env.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `{
      viewer {
        accounts(filter: { accountTag: "${process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT}" }) {
          r2StorageAdaptiveGroups(
            limit: 9999
            filter: { datetime_geq: "${date.toISOString()}" }
          ) {
            max {
              payloadSize
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`
  })
})


const bodyStorage = await storage.json()
const bytes = bodyStorage.data.viewer.accounts[0].r2StorageAdaptiveGroups[0].max.payloadSize

console.log(`R2 read=${aUsage}% (${classATotal} req) write=${bUsage}% (${classBTotal} req) storage=${bytesUsage}% (${megabytes}Mb)`)

if (aUsage > 50 || bUsage > 50 || bytesUsage > 50) {
  console.log("over 50% usage")
}
```

this assumes you have a .env or .dev.vars file with these three values filled out

```
CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT=
CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN=
EMAIL=
```

Generate a [token](https://dash.cloudflare.com/profile/api-tokens).

Your [account ID](https://dash.cloudflare.com/?to=/:account/workers) can be found on the right.

Then assuming you are running Node v20.6+ (which can read .env files) it will just be `node --env-file .env main.js`.

#### Worker email

I wanted to automate this into a CloudFlare Worker. I found that there is good integration with MailChannel so that emails can be sent from an authenticated domain. There is a lot of steps to doing that and veers off the topic. So, I'll just [link](https://github.com/CodaBool/analytics) that here but here is the intro paragraph:

> This Worker sends weekly emails with a percent report on all class A, class B, and storage size metrics for R2. Uses CF Worker and GitHub Actions for automation.